# Making an addition accumulator in python

Tags: python

What is desired is to

```
    def accumulator():
        def addition():
             something here 
             and others
        return addition
```

where

```
A = accumulator()

A(10) 
10
A(10)
20
```

using Message Passing such that every accumulator() will have the overall sum at the end.

I have no idea how to start. . . I would be really appreciative if you could help!
Thanks

Comment: What version do you use: Python 2 or Python 3? If you use Python 3, you can do this by closure.

Comment: can you edit your question and finish your sentences? "Using Message Passing from", from what? You are using this function like an object in your example, do you need to write an object Accumulator?

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary The input is not inside a list though.

Comment: @user3251511 You can use `itertools.count` or a while loop to get an infinite loop. And you can even send data back to a generator function using its `.send()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just another variant, with closures.

```
def accumulator():
    sum = 0
    def addition(n):
         nonlocal sum
         sum += n
         return sum
    return addition
```

Comment: Just wondering but why can't I just use sum without the "nonlocal" ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can get the desired effect by updating a class variable.

```
class accumulator(object):
    summation = 0
    def __call__(self,val):
        accumulator.summation+=val
        print accumulator.summation

A = accumulator()
A(10)
A(10)
B = accumulator()
B(10)
B(100)
```

This will give:

```
10
20
30
130
```

and every instance will have the correct value in the `summation` attribute.

If you want to keep the summations of `A` and `B` separate:

```
class accumulator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.summation = 0
    def __call__(self,val):
        self.summation+=val
        print self.summation
```

Comment: However if I would like to make A and B summation separate?

Comment: I added some extra code to the answer for this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a coroutine, as Aशwini चhaudhary suggested:

```
def coroutine(func):
    """
    http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/
    http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html
    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        gen = func(*args, **kw)
        gen.send(None)
        return gen
    return wrapper

@coroutine
def accumulator():
    val = 0
    while True:
        val += (yield val)
```

which can be used like this:

```
A = accumulator().send
print(A(10))
# 10

print(A(10))
# 20

print(A(10))
# 30
```